# How can I use recyclerviewadapter with sqlite in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite database in android. I couldn't be able to see image data in `RecyclerView`. How can I see that in the activity page with a `RecyclerView` adapter?

I tried this but `EpisodesAdapter episodesAdapter = new EpisodeAdapter(this, cursorEpisode, 0);` this line is giving an error.

```
try {
    EpisodesAdapter episodesAdapter = new EpisodeAdapter(this,cursorEpisode,0);
    rvEpisodeImage.setAdapter(episodesAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Succeed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is the adapter class

```
public class EpisodesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EpisodesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private CursorAdapter mEpisodesAdapter;
    private Context mEpisodesContext;
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;

    public EpisodesAdapter(final Context mEpisodesContext, Cursor cursor) {
        this.mEpisodesContext = mEpisodesContext;
        mEpisodesAdapter = new CursorAdapter(mEpisodesContext, cursor,0 ) {
            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                // Inflate the view here
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_of_parts,viewGroup, false);
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                ImageView ivParts = view.findViewById(R.id.ivParts);

                String sEpisodeName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("EPISODE_NAME"));

                int iImgPath = (int) context.getResources().getIdentifier(sEpisodeName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

                ivParts.setImageResource(iImgPath);
            }
        };
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EpisodesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mEpisodesAdapter.newView(mEpisodesContext, mEpisodesAdapter.getCursor(), parent);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return (ViewHolder) holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EpisodesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mEpisodesAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
        mEpisodesAdapter.bindView(holder.itemView,mEpisodesContext,mEpisodesAdapter.getCursor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEpisodesAdapter.getCount();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView ivParts;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivParts = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivParts);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? What should I do to get a view in `RecyclerView`?

```java
EpisodesAdapter episodesAdapter = new EpisodeAdapter(this, cursorEpisode, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you read the values from the cursor first and save the values in an `ArrayList`. Then pass the `ArrayList` to the adapter instead of passing the cursor.

The problem in your adapter is, you should get the same value from the cursor for every item in your `RecyclerView` as you are not actually iterating over the cursor when the position changes. The `Cursor` works as a pointer and hence you need to move to the next pointer to get the next element in your cursor. Hence I would like to suggest something like the following.

Declare a class to handle your data first.

```
public class Episode {
    public String episodeName;
    public int imagePath;
}
```

Then after getting the cursor from your database, iterate through the cursor and populate an `ArrayList` of `Episode` like the following.

```
public ArrayList<Episode> getEpisodesFromCursor(Cursor cursor, Context context) {
    ArrayList<Episode> episodes = new ArrayList<Episode>();
    if (cursor == null) return episodes;

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        Episode episode = new Episode();
        String episodeName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("EPISODE_NAME"));
        episode.episodeName = episodeName;
        episode.imagePath = (int) context.getResources().getIdentifier(episodeName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        episodes.add(episode);
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());

    return episodes;
}
```

Pass the cursor to the function above to get an `ArrayList` of your items. Then modify your adapter to accept the `ArrayList<Episode>` and then change your other functions accordingly.

Once you have passed the `ArrayList`, modify the `bindView` function accordingly to show proper image and other data.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, int position) {
    ImageView ivParts = view.findViewById(R.id.ivParts);

    String sEpisodeName = episodes.get(position).episodeName;

    int iImgPath = (int) context.getResources().getIdentifier(sEpisodeName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

    ivParts.setImageResource(iImgPath);
}
```

I just have added some sample implementation and you need to change the code as per your need. I hope that helps!

Edit:

Moreover, you are getting the error as the adapter constructor is expecting different parameters. You need to modify the constructor of your adapter anyway if you are using an `ArrayList` as I have suggested.

Comment: I understand the idea but not make it work in my code. all my data saved in string. and additional data also avaliable
```java
public static final String EPISODE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String EPISODE_NAME = "episode_name";
    public static final String EPISODE_IMAGE = "episode_image";
    public static final String EPISODE_INFO = "episode_info";
    public static final String EPISODE_TAGS = "episode_tags";
   ...
```
mine adapter seems works but in the activity page i want to call with ```layout manager```